# Can baby villagers with food in their inventory break villager breeders?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

One flaw I have in my villager breeder is that sometimes as they're passing around carrots, 1-64 carrot(s) falls below them to where baby villagers are transported away by a water stream. The carrots flow right into where baby villagers wait to become an adult, and I heard baby villagers can pick up crops as well.

If that's true, can the baby villagers mess up the way the breeder works? Will baby villagers give other baby villagers carrots?

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned which particular villager breeder design you are speaking of.

Let's assume it is impulseSV's design

Baby villagers will not mess up the breeding unless those babies fail to fall into the water stream and grow to be adults within the breeder itself. This creates crowding in the breeder and also it creates unnecessary lag on the server.

To prevent this issue, TangoTek came up with a solution to put a zombie in center of villager breeder and seal it off so that the zombie cannot attack the villagers. It should only scare them. Using this "scaring logic" baby villagers will always fall into the water stream and the server lag due to crowding will be prevented.